# проблемы с регистрацией и входом

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

здравствуйте, на сайте перестали работать регистрация и вход, в консоли выходит такая ошибка:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Function.n.parseJSON (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at Object.success (init.js:154)
at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
```

кусок init.js с ошибкой в 154 строке такой:

```
function modalFormHandler(){
$('#authRegForm').submit(function(){
    var form = $(this);
    var str = form.serialize();
    var host = '/billing-proxy/authreg.php?';
    $.get( host + str, function( data ) {
        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
        if (jsonData.doc.error && jsonData.doc.error.detail){
            $('.js-modalErrors').html(jsonData.doc.error.detail.$);
        }
        else if (jsonData.doc.error && jsonData.doc.error.msg){
            $('.js-modalErrors').html(jsonData.doc.error.msg.$);
        }
        else if (jsonData.doc.ok){
            window.location.href = BILLING_HOST + jsonData.doc.ok.$;
        }
        else if (jsonData.doc.auth){
            var newStr = str.replace('out=json', '');
            window.location.href = BILLING_HOST + newStr;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
}
```

как это возможно исправить?

Comment: Ссылку на сайт, если не против, посмотрю.

Comment: https://timhost.ru/

Comment: стоит заглушка, ничего просмотреть не могу.

Comment: ошибся, сейчас поменял ссылку. нужно смотреть "вход в биллинг"

Comment: что именно должно не работать? При нажатии на "Вход в биллинг" всплывает форма, всё как нужно...

Comment: сам вход на сайт. невозможно зарегистрироваться и войти. при нажатии кнопки входа или регистрации выходит эта ошибка

Comment: что правил перед тем как перестало работать?

Comment: ничего, совсем недавно само перестало. но не я один имею доступ к стайту, поэтому...

Comment: само по себе отвалиться точно не могло никак. Значить были какие-то изменения о которых ты забыл или возможно ещё кто мог изменить. Есть какие-то контактные данные? Свяжусь и посмотрим что там случилось.

Comment: система показывает, что в этом файле не было изменений с 2016 года

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68794/discussion-on-question-by-rudolf-otto-----).